# Pig: extract records that are not distinct by a column

Tags: apache-pig

I want to extract records that are not distinct by a column, how could I implement it?

For example input:

```
(user1, value1, value2)
(user1, value3, value4)
(user2, value5, value6)
(user3, value7, value8)
(user4, value9, value10)
(user4, value11, value12)
```

after extracting records that has repeated value of column 1, output would be:

```
(user1, value1, value2)
(user1, value3, value4)
(user4, value9, value10)
(user4, value11, value12)
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if this works for you. For testing purpose i used value1 and value2 as chararray  but in your actual code change the value1 and value2 as int or long

```
input.txt
user1,value1,value2
user1,value3,value4
user2,value5,value6
user3,value7,value8
user4,value9,value10
user4,value11,value12

PigScript
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USINg PigStorage(',') AS (user:chararray,value1:chararray,value2:chararray);
B = GROUP A BY user;
C = FOREACH B  GENERATE FLATTEN(A),COUNT(A) AS cnt;
D = FILTER C BY cnt >1;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE A::user,A::value1,A::value2;
DUMP E;

Output:
(user1,value1,value2)
(user1,value3,value4)
(user4,value9,value10)
(user4,value11,value12)
```

Comment: @DanZhu, If my answer helped, please mark this question as answered.